How to run globally installed coverage on a package inside a virtual enviroment?
I'd like to run a coverage check with the following configuration:

coverage is installed globally on the system (via pipx).
pytest in installed inside the virtual environment of the project.

(Inside the venv) When I run coverage run -m pytest I get the error No module named 'pytest'.
How to reproduce
pipx install coverage

python -m venv venv
source ./venv/bin/activate
pip install pytest
coverage run -m pytest

Here are some other outputs (inside the venv)

command: pytest --version.

result: pytest 8.3.4


command: coverage run --source=. ./venv/bin/python -m pytest

result:

CoverageWarning: No data was collected.
Couldn't run '[...]/venv/bin/python' as Python code: SyntaxError: invalid or missing encoding declaration






When you use the coverage command, you are running in the global Python environment, so it won't find your virtual environment.  Can you say more about why you don't want to install coverage in your virtual environment?

That was my guess. My question is how can I make it use the virtual environment.

Can you say more about why you don't want to install coverage in your virtual environment?
Because that's just a workaround.

